# octave load function

Tags: matlab, octave

i'm trying to load a mat file from a subdirectory using the following code:

```
% filename_str is read from a text file
directoryname_str = "./data";
f = fullfile(directoryname_str, filename_str);
load(f);
```

when i run this sequence, load says it can't find the file...but when i copy or type the relative path and the file name by hand into an active octave session, everything works like a champ with no errors.

i assume this has something to do with how octave searches for mat files? if so, what's the correct environment variable or function call i need to make in order for this code to work?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you sure that what you put into the variable `f` is the same as what you input manually in octave?
2. Are you also in the same directory? Because you're specifying relative paths, this should be the case.. you can get the current directory octave is in with `pwd`
3. And last of all, you can double check file existence in octave itself using [exist](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/exist.html)

   ```
   exist(f,'file')
   ```

   If this returns false, there's definitely something wrong with your current directory, are something's very weird going on..